# Import error: no such process (Numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, installation

I am trying to run a `python` program that imports `numpy`. I have successfully installed `numpy`. However, when I re-run the program, I get the following error. I saw multiple posts of this issue on Stackoverflow, but couldn't find too much information of this error with regards to numpy. Completely lost on how to resolve. I tried running with both python2 and python3 (I have installed numpy for both python2 and python3.

Also, I want to point out that this is not "Module not found error."

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "practice.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: No such process
```

Comment: I am downloading this through Mobaxterm. So i'm assuming it does this internally?

Comment: Exactly, so I don't think it is a problem with the "path?" Maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: One reason could be that you have different versions of Numpy installed on your machine. Make sure there is only version of numpy and uninstall the older ones.